# Optimize large ST_Intersect query, match 1.8m OSM streets to 317k polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to match spatially all streets in Open Street Maps (OSM) in Brazil to the 2010 Census Enumeration district shapefile in Postgis.

I imported all files to Postgis with WGS84 projection and included spatial indexes (gist).

OSM data comes from geofabrik planet_osm_line, which I filter to extract only the streets. There are 1.8 million streets.

The Enumeration district shapefile has 317 thousand polygons. The shapefiles are not too precise, so ideally I would add a buffer around them to make sure.

ST_Intersects directly on streets to enumeration districts was taking for ever. So, to reduced the numer of spatial matches, by first joinnig the OSM streets with the municipality polygons, creating the OSM_Streets_by_Mun table. There are 5560 municipalities in Brasil and Enumeration districts are nested in them.

So the  final query, bellow, includes numeric matching of state and municipal code, to reduce spatial matches to only within municipalities.

Still, the query is not finishing on a 4 core 128gb of RAM server even after 5 days.

Any ideas on how to improve preformance?

```
CREATE TABLE OSM_Streets_by_SetorCensitario AS
SELECT OSM_Streets_by_Mun.*, setor_censitarioL.geom
FROM OSM_Streets_by_Mun, setor_censitarioL
WHERE   OSM_Streets_by_Mun.cod_UF = substring(setor_censitarioL.cd_geocodi,1,2) AND
        OSM_Streets_by_Mun.cod_mun = substring(setor_censitarioL.cd_geocodi,1,7) AND
        ST_Intersects(way,ST_Buffer(setor_censitarioL.geom,0.005))=true
```

Here is the output from EXPLAIN command on the query

```
"Merge Join  (cost=359099.59..765616.74 rows=248521 width=3777)"
"  Merge Cond: ((("substring"((setor_censitariol.cd_geocodi)::text, 1, 2)) = (osm_streets_by_mun.cod_uf)::text) AND (("substring"((setor_censitariol.cd_geocodi)::text, 1, 7)) = (osm_streets_by_mun.cod_mun)::text))"
"  Join Filter: st_intersects(osm_streets_by_mun.way, st_buffer(setor_censitariol.geom, 0.005::double precision))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=86016.75..86808.33 rows=316634 width=2145)"
"        Sort Key: ("substring"((setor_censitariol.cd_geocodi)::text, 1, 2)), ("substring"((setor_censitariol.cd_geocodi)::text, 1, 7))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on setor_censitariol  (cost=0.00..57088.34 rows=316634 width=2145)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=273082.84..277547.26 rows=1785768 width=1648)"
"        Sort Key: osm_streets_by_mun.cod_uf, osm_streets_by_mun.cod_mun"
"        ->  Seq Scan on osm_streets_by_mun  (cost=0.00..87647.68 rows=1785768 width=1648)"
```

Comment: Try a manual (I not know is an internal automatic) pre-check, `... AND (way && setor_censitarioL.geom) AND ST_Intersects(...)`

Comment: The operation `ST_Intersects(way,ST_Buffer(setor_censitarioL.geom,0.005))=true`  seems http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html that is optimized for this case (and not need the use of pre-check by &&)

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove text matching from the query - spatial would be just fine, otherwise it would not use the spatial index, just iterate sequentially over both tables;
2. Pre-calculate your ST_Buffer in the table;
3. Add spatial indexes to your table and CLUSTER your table using it;
4. Don't write =true for boolean functions, they are enough by themselves.

Comment: The biggest improvement is number 2).  When you use `ST_Buffer` you create a new object and that wont have an index. Regarding 1) I would do the testing with and without, but same as 2) if you use `substring(` you may affect the use of the index. So precalculate a column with the right value and create an index there.

Answer (score 2):

Any (most) function(s) used in WHERE on geometry is causing that your index is not taken into plan. Of course you can recalculate all values or add some columns (like ST_Buffer(geom,0.005) and create indexes on them. If you don't want to touch the tables and need to use function use it also in the index -

```
Create index table_geom_buffer_idx on table using gist(st_buffer(geom,0.005));
```

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Based on suggestions of the other questions (tks!) I ran some tests of different specifications. [It is all docummented in this code, along with EXPLAIN output and run time for each query](https://github.com/lucasmation/osm_cnefe_import/blob/master/aux_files/test_queries_for_osm_setorCensitario_intersection.sql).

The fastest solution I found was:

- Creating an index based on both the municipal code and the spatial variable and CLUSTERING on that index

`CREATE INDEX setor_censitarioL_index3 ON setor_censitarioL USING gist (cod_mun,geom);
CLUSTER setor_censitarioL   using setor_censitarioL_index3;
CREATE INDEX OSM_Streets_by_Mun_index3  ON OSM_Streets_by_Mun USING gist (cod_mun,way);
CLUSTER     OSM_Streets_by_Mun using OSM_Streets_by_Mun_index3;`

- ST_DWithin()  instead of pre-computing a buffer.

`CREATE TABLE OSM_Streets_by_SetorCensitario AS
SELECT osm_id, cd_geocodi as cod_setor
FROM OSM_Streets_by_mun
INNER JOIN  setor_censitarioL
ON  OSM_Streets_by_mun.cod_mun=setor_censitarioL.cod_mun AND
    ST_DWithin(way,geom,0.005);**strong text**`

This gets the job done in 1h36m (4core, 128gb ram server). I compared the results of EXPLAIN of that query with other options  (pre compiling the geom with buffer, using only the spatial varible in the index) and that seemed the cheapest (most efficient) one.